# Unexpected behavior insert/query MySQL during periods of high contention

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.6

I'm encountering an unexpected situation with inserting/querying particular records in the following table during periods of high contention.  I believe there is a race condition in the database.

```
CREATE TABLE `business_objects` (
   `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
   `obj_id` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
   `obj_type` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
   `created_at` datetime(6) NOT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
   UNIQUE KEY `index_business_objects_on_obj_type_and_obj_id`
     (`obj_type`,`obj_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

The steps to reproduce are:

1. Check if record exists in table using this query

   ```
   SELECT *
   FROM business_objects
   WHERE obj_type = 'Tip'
   AND obj_id = '7616904'
   ```
2. If this query is null, attempt to create

   ```
   INSERT INTO business_objects (obj_type, obj_id)
   VALUES ('Tip', '7616904')
   ```
3. If another thread has already created a record with the same attributes this `insert` will fail and raise a uniqueness MySQL error.  In this scenario, I catch the error and run the same query in step 1 to get the record.

   ```
   SELECT * 
   FROM business_objects
   WHERE obj_type = 'Tip'
   AND obj_id = '7616904'
   ```
4. The query returns an empty result.

My expectation is that if the index uniqueness constraint is violated than the record should be committed to the table.  What am I missing?

Comment: well you don't need step one

Comment: Perhaps in this example but in the application a majority of the records already exist and the `INSERT` is the exception.

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-transaction-isolation-levels.html